# protractor --elementExplorer with configuration file

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I would like to try and use the --elementExplorer option to see what I can do with browser.manage().logs().

Can you specify a .conf file when passing --elementExplorer? I was hoping to define multiCapabilities with loggingPrefs settings that would let me programmatically interact with the console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably it will help you. Element explore will ignore your specs, not set up your framework (e.g. jasmine, mocha, cucumber), and only allow you to pass in 1 capability, but will honor every other parameter in your config.
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#testing-out-protractor-interactively